# Manipulation of magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Two months from now I will give a presentation at my university to popularise physics among high school students and I started to work on interesting experiments which would draw attention. The only one of my ideas which I don't know if it's possible to do is to make an arm mounted electromagnetic device which could attract items made out of ferromagnetic materials into the hand of the user from around $0.5-1m$.

 The problems I came across:

- I could not produce such a magnetic field with the magnetic field simulators I have
- I did not found any useful information in half a year(!) about such "directed" magnetic fields, only conspiracy theories and free energy theories... (such a shame)

So my main question is : Is it possible to somehow produce a magnetic fields like that and if the answer is yes how should I start looking for a magnetic field like that? (I am aware of all the dangers of it, I need only a piece of information to start from to be able to calculate all of it's capabilities and dangers.)

Comment: One can manipulate magnetic fields to simulate a magnetic pole .  . Imagine a solenoid in the shape of a cone. The north pole wide circles the south pole tiny (or vice verso) .  Reduce your ambitions to 10 or so centimeters, looking at the numbers in Chris' answer. I do not off hand see if it will have the dipole forces  though, for something hand held.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle it's possible. In practice you're not going to be able to make a magnet that can attract ferromagnetic materials from a meter away handheld. Not to mention said device would be *extraordinarily* dangerous. No one likes pieces of metal flying at them at high speeds from a meter away or more.

The main problem is that magnetic forces drop off *very* quickly with increased distance. The magnetic field of a dipole magnet falls off as $B\propto {1\over r^3}$. A ferromagnetic object acquires a dipole moment roughly proportional to $B$. A dipole in a magnetic field feels a force proportional to its dipole moment times the gradient of the field. The gradient of the field falls off as $1\over r^4$. (Note that you can't do better than a dipole with a localized source: any other field falls off faster.)

Putting this all together tells you that, for a dipole field, the force on a ferromagnetic object falls off as $1\over r^7$! So if the force is barely enough to start something moving from a meter away, it's enormous at half a meter. In practice, this means that any magnet of a reasonable size can't attract anything ferromagnetic from any appreciable distance.

Comment: Good and helpful answer!

Comment: Since my question is about "directed" (I know that a magnetic field can't be directed literally) magnetic fields it would not require such powerful magnetic fields. I am aware of all the dangers of it but of course I will only do this experiment if it is safe and tested in a smaller scale.(A good solution I think would be to generate the magnetic field in pulses so the object could not accelerate to dangerously high velocities. ) And I know that in theory it is possible.

Comment: @L.Gyula "It would not require such powerful magnetic fields." Sorry, but it would. "Directed" or not, the force on an object due to a magnetic field depends on the gradient of the field- directing it doesn't reduce the field required. This needs to be at least large enough to counteract frictional forces at one meter, and unavoidably gets larger very quickly as the object gets closer.

Comment: It would be possible however to make something move with a magnet permanent or electric at distances well over a meter. This could be done with simple dollar store magnets.

Comment: @Lambda Yes, permanent magnets are much easier to move from a distance than ferromagnetic materials.

Comment: Check this out: https://youtu.be/Pt9547aoRd4